# Running a python script as a windows service after converting to exe

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, windows-services

I have a python script which is raising a socket for communication purposes, I've managed to convert it to exe using [Pyinstaller](https://mborgerson.com/creating-an-executable-from-a-python-script) and run it successfully by double clicking on it.

I tried to make the exe a windows service using the following [guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/) but when I ran the service through services.msc, I got:
`Windows could not start the test1 service on Local Computer
Error 1053: the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion`

I wonder whether **each** python script can realy become a windows service, or it has some criterias , as I didn't see this in the `guide` above.

I tried to take it more simple ,and created a python script of the following code:
`while True:
    z = 10
    print z`
Now I created an exe file and a service, when trying to run it I got:

`Windows could not start the test1 service on Local Computer

 Error 1067: the process terminated unexpectedly`

Can somebody please direct me, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe read [ask] and [mcve], and recast your question accordingly?

Comment: @boardrider: Knowing how to ask is not an issue here, thanks

Comment: You may get some responses if you included a [mcve], but - Okay, to each his own.